# Making Custom Logger available across Multiple modules

Tags: python, logging

I had created a custom logger for my purpose using python and made it a utility. I created its context-based and had it created with custom handlers for different scenarios. I am trying to make my custom logger visible across all modules. But I am not able to this. I don't want to reuse these lines in each of my modules just for the logger and pass on my context and config just for that.

```
logger = myLogger(config, context) # config has data for context based custom handling
```

In my main module, I just made the logger object global so that other methods can use the logger without any further add ons. Is there any way I can do the same across modules.

In many similar queries. what is suggested is

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

But this does not pass on my custom handlers also.

Can someone please advise how I can achieve this.

Make my custom logger global for my whole run time so that I don't have to declare whenever I have to.

my code is like this

```
def main():
    args=argparse.ArgumentParser
    parser.add_argument('-context','--context')
    parser.add_argument('-cfg','--cfg')
    config=configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(cfg)
    global logger
    logger=myLogger(config,context)
    ## here context is my  section name from config. which has details for my current process. 
    ##my myLogger reads   from a log  file config   details in configparser onject
    ## there i will remove my detault handlers and add my custom handlers  and return the logger object back to main  so  this is  how it works
    ## making logger as global in main makes it visible to other methods  in same module as main 
    ## but  i am trying to make  my logger visible to other modules also if i call the methods from those module



if __name__==__main__:
    main()
```

Comment: Next time please be aware of language and format.

Comment: sure. will make a note thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My way of doing it:

**Logging.py**

```
import logging

# Your custom stuff

logger = myLogger(config, context)
```

**Every_other_file.py**

```
from Logging import logger
```

### Edit: Change the config later on

**Logging.py**

```
import logging

# Your custom stuff

logger = myLogger(config, context)

def change_config(config):
    global logger
    logger = myLogger(config, context)

def set_logger(config)
    global logger
    logger = myLogger(config.context)
```

** main.py**

```
config = something
Logging.set_logger(config)
```

Something like that. My point is you can call a method with it you can change the value

Comment: thanks for coming back. i have to call this inside  a function say main . as my  dont know what  config is yet and am  reading that from  console.  logger = myLogger(config, context) .  even though i can make my context   the same for my particular   code run . the Config is bound to  change. I cannot  hard code it .

Comment: wont i get an error ,config is not defined for logger=myLogger(config,context).i cannot hard code context but not the config. i am trying to not hard code  . 
 edited my question to add the code.

Comment: Could your edit your question and add this Code. It is hard to read with no formatting

Comment: Should't it be `config.context` with a dot instead of a comma?

Comment: my config has  context specific  details i need to fetch for  more than one cases. that is why i had details a config file and am reading that config file in a config parser object and  creating my custom logger based on these details .

Comment: May be there is no other way around LEGB . Though there might be some hack that would allow me to do this.